# ios app crashes each time i click on the search bar, while retreving data from parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

each time i try and click on the search bar, the app keeps crashing, below is the code for the UItableview used with the parse.com SDK, is there something i missed on the code. its crashing when the search bar is clicked, before the keyboard gets loaded.

## #

NSRangeException', reason: ' -[NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' ** First throw call stack: ( 0 CoreFoundation 0x0000000102cb1795 __exceptionPreprocess + 165 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000102a14991 objc_exception_throw + 43 2 CoreFoundation

## #

this is the view did load method to load search bar

```
@interface CarTableViewController () <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>
{
GADBannerView *bannerView_;
}
@ property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchBar * searchbar;
@ property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchDisplayController *searchcontroller;
@ property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * SearchResults;
@end

@implementation CarTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
//search bar

self.searchbar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchbar;
self.searchcontroller = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar: self.searchbar contentsController: self];
self.searchcontroller.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchcontroller.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.searchcontroller.delegate = self;
CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, self.searchbar.frame.size.height);
self.tableView.contentOffset = offset;
self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];
}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
```

this is the load for parse

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
if (self) {
    self.parseClassName = @"movienow";
    self.textKey = @"mName";
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
    self.paginationEnabled = NO;
}
return self;
}

//where to search and other

- (void) filterResults: (NSString *)searchTerm{

[self.SearchResults removeAllObjects];

PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: self.parseClassName]; // table in which you are looking for
[query whereKeyExists: @ "mName"]; // column which you are looking for
[query whereKey: @ "mName" containsString : searchTerm];

NSArray * results = [query findObjects];
[self.SearchResults addObjectsFromArray: results];
}

- (BOOL) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *) controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString: (NSString *) searchstring {
[self filterResults: searchstring];
return YES;
}


- (NSInteger) Tableview: (UITableView *) Tableview numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger) section {
if (Tableview == self.tableView) {
    return self.objects.count;
} else {
    return self.SearchResults.count;
}
}

- (void) callbackLoadObjectsFromParse: (NSArray *)result error:(NSError *) error {
if (!error) {
    [self.SearchResults removeAllObjects],
    [self.SearchResults addObjectsFromArray: result];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
} else {
    NSLog (@ "Error:%@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CarTableCell";
CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if (tableView == self.tableView) {

//cell.mName.text = [object objectForKey:@"objectld"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[object objectForKey:@"mName"]);

}
else if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
    PFObject *searchUser = [self.SearchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@",[searchUser objectForKey:@"mName"]);
        }

// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}
```

crash log

2014-01-23 15:58:23.440 MovieTimeLK2[8442:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '** -[**NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102cb1795 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102a14991 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c578e5 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 213
    3   MovieTimeLK2                        0x0000000100005aab -[CarTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:object:] + 2155
    4   MovieTimeLK2                        0x0000000100078c7d -[PFQueryTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 200
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000101742b8a -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 348
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010172a836 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2297
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010173b381 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 207
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001016d2b27 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 354
    9   QuartzCore                          0x00000001010c7a22 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 151
    10  QuartzCore                          0x00000001010bc589 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 363
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001016c7470 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 521
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001019a46c3 -[UISearchDisplayControllerContainerView setFrame:] + 113
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010199de5f -[UISearchDisplayController setActive:animated:] + 9697
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001019a0576 -[UISearchDisplayController searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:] + 277
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001018e31b0 -[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) _searchFieldBeginEditing] + 97
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001016780ae -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 104
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000101678044 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 17
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010174c450 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 203
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000101c83594 -[UITextField willAttachFieldEditor:] + 576
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001017513d7 -[UIFieldEditor becomeFieldEditorForView:] + 725
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000101c7b2df -[UITextField _becomeFirstResponder] + 143
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001018e5eb3 -[UISearchBarTextField _becomeFirstResponder] + 92
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010179fc0c -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 340
    24  UIKit                               0x00000001016c6abc -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 99
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000101c7ae53 -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 51
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010198820c -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 118
    27  UIKit                               0x0000000101989fc0 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:] + 1768
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010198050a _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 188
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010197f470 -[UIGestureRecognizer *updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 357
    30  UIKit                               0x0000000101983829 _*_UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 53
    31  UIKit                               0x00000001019837b1 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 257
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010197b87d _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 93
    33  UIKit                               0x00000001016ac925 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 928
    34  UIKit                               0x00000001016ad5e5 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 910
    35  UIKit                               0x0000000101686fa2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211
    36  UIKit                               0x0000000101674d7f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9549
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c40ec1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c40792 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c5c61f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c5bf33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    41  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001049873a0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    42  UIKit                               0x0000000101677043 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    43  MovieTimeLK2                        0x0000000100006c33 main + 115
    44  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001035e65fd start + 1
    45  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: check your array count,this crash occures index not found in array

Comment: Is there a method being called when the searchBar begins editing? My guess is as soon as you begin editing, it runs the query with searchText being blank, thus returning nothing - but still returning so no error. Obviously then the array is empty and so even element 0 does not exist...

Comment: Infact, according to your crash report it seems you do in fact fire the method on searchFieldDidBeginEditing... Rather fire on searchFieldDidChangeValue (something like that) and check if the array returned is empty or not before passing it to searchResults.addObjectsFromArray

Answer (score 2):

From the crash log posted, it seems that your problem is in `PFObject *searchUser = [self.SearchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

But that would be strange if you already use `return self.SearchResults.count;` in `- (NSInteger) Tableview: (UITableView *) Tableview numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger) section`

The first thing that comes to my mind is where you call `[self.SearchResults removeAllObjects];` in `- (void) filterResults: (NSString *)searchTerm` , I suggest using the below code:

```
- (void) filterResults: (NSString *)searchTerm{

     PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: self.parseClassName]; // table in which you are looking for
     [query whereKeyExists: @ "mName"]; // column which you are looking for
     [query whereKey: @ "mName" containsString : searchTerm];

     NSArray * results = [query findObjects];
     self.SearchResults = [results mutableCopy];

}
```

Update:

Since it crashes with the first typing, then make sure that `numberOfRowsInSection` returns `self.SearchResults.count` not `self.objects.count`, if it does but doesn't return zero, try replacing `self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];` with `self.searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in your `viewDidLoad`

Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: could you help out whit how it should be changed too

Comment: try to log the `self.SearchResults.count` in all your functions & see where it is zero

Comment: it crashes the minute i try and enter text in the search bar, so the filter function does not even get called

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't initializate the mutable array change

```
self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];
```

to

```
self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```